# differentiable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to solve this problem

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ a differentiable function with continuous derivative.

Suppose further that $f$ is twice differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Prove that if $f(a)=f(b)$ and $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$, then
  exist $x_1, x_2 \in (a,b)$ with $x_1 \neq x_2$ such that $f''(x_1) = f''(x_2)$.

I'm trying to solve this problem graphically intuitively ; I tried, and likely the problem is real: if $f(a) = f(b)$ and $f'(a) = f'(b) = 0$, the points $a$ and $b$ are the points of maximum and minimum for the function.
but how can you prove that there are $x_1, x_2 \in (a,b)$ with $x_1 \neq x_2$
such that $f''(x_1) = f''(x_2)$?

Comment: The last paragraph of your question doesn't make much sense. You could consider fixing it.

Comment: There's this weird spacing when you write $[a,b]$ and $(a,b)$ before the second bracket/parenthesis that I can't get rid of by editing. Weird.

Comment: @Patrick: Done.

Comment: @Didier : What was the problem exactly? I looked at the edit but saw nothing, just you replacing some characters by the exact same characters.

Comment: @Patrick: What we saw as `b` plus a space was in fact a compound of the letter `b` and of two invisible pseudo-characters attached to it and translated by the system as a space. That is, an encoding gone awry (but please do not ask me for more precise details...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function is constant, everything is easy.

If the function is not constant, it attains a maximum and a minimum value in our interval, and these values are distinct.

The max and min cannot both occur at endpoints, since $f(a)=f(b)$. So there is a local extremum in $(a,b)$, and therefore a point $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.  Now you should be able to use Rolle's Theorem to show that there exist points $x_1\in(a,c)$ and $x_2\in(c,b)$ such that $f''(x_1)=f''(x_2)=0$.

Comment: A nitpick: Why do you essentially prove Rolle's Theorem and then appeal to it?

Comment: @David Mitra: Of course you are right. I wanted to connect the finding of $c$ with something familiar, to make the geometry more concrete-seeming.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Apply the [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) three times (or [Rolle's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolles_theorem) if you prefer).

Applying it once to $f$ over $[a,b]$ gives you a point $c$ with $a<c<b$ where $f'(c)=0$.

Now apply the Mean Value Theorem to $f'$ on each of the intervals $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$.

(Note that the Mean Value Theorem gives you a point $c$ *strictly between* the endpoints of the interval that you're working over.)

---

It's not true that $a$ and $b$ necessarily give the minimum and maximum of the function. They could in fact give neither. For instance, the graph could resemble a $\sin$ wave over $[0,2\pi]$ that's been "smoothed out" at the endpoints (so that the derivative is zero at the endpoints).